# Left navigation that's position fixed loses hover state on page scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a left navigation bar - position fixed, within the bar I have link with a white hover state which works.

However in Chrome 36, when I scroll the page and you hover over the links - the hover states does not apply. Its almost like the hover area scrolls up the page with the page scroll.

I haven't got any code I can share but was hopeful that someone would recognise this bug and share a fix.

Thank you for any feedback.

```
.left-shelf {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 51px;
    left: 0;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #34474f;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

with a list of links within:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">something</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I fail to replicate the error, it's working as intended for me. Chrome Version 36. http://jsfiddle.net/2dvuc64o/

Comment: Was not able to replicate in Version 36.0.1985.143 m. Made jsFiddle to try and replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/dprust/yzfaLk3e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the problem, on the parent, parent I have these properties - when commented out the pages as expected!

```
#page {
/* position: relative; */
/* z-index: 99; */
/* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; */
}
```